# PSCP Command Errror

Tags: ssh, putty, scp

Can anybody explain what i am doing wrong here. I am trying to copy an entire directory up to a remote server.

**"c:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe" -l mleyland -pw Password5 -p mleyland@9X.XX:/home/mleyland/hvn01/ D:\TEMP_BACKUP\ZIP*.***

I get the error message.

**/home/mleyland/hvn01/: is a directory**

So i change the command to.

**"c:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe" -l mleyland -pw Password5 -p mleyland@9X.XX:/home/mleyland/hvn01/*.* D:\TEMP_BACKUP\ZIP*.***

And i get

**wildcard '*.*' matched no files**

The first command i was running worked fine, However i needed a way to save the password so i can run without user intervention.

**c:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY>pscp D:\TEMP_BACKUP\ZIP mleyland@XX.XX7.38 /home
/mleyland**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're most definitly missing `-r`, the target seems a little odd too.
Try this:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe" -r -pw Password5 -p mleyland@9X.XX:/home/mleyland/hvn01/ D:\TEMP_BACKUP\
```

`-l` is redundant if using `user@host`.

Comment: This works fine but it downloads form the remote side not uploads ??

Comment: If you want the contents of `D:\TEMP_BACKUP` to go to `9X.XX`, reverse the order of the 2 arguments. It's `pscp.exe [opts] [user@host:]SOURCE [user@host:]TARGET`

Comment: Thanks Fuero, Just to let future people know this is how i got it to work. "c:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe" -r -pw PassWord D:\TEMP_BACKUP\ZIP mleyland@xx.xx.xx.xx:/home/mleyland/hvn01